# Hortonworks Data Platform (Hadoop) installation single node cluster on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

I am referring the manual installation guide (http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.9.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1.html) provided on Hortonworks website. I am facing issue while configuring the remote repositories (http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.9.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-3.html). When I am running the command **“sudo wget http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/ubuntu12/2.x/hdp.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hdp.list”** on the Ubuntu 12.04 terminal, it shows error **“404 NOT FOUND”**.

Below is the error:

–2015-04-13 12:59:10– http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/ubuntu12/2.x/hdp.list
Resolving public-repo-1.hortonworks.com (public-repo-1.hortonworks.com)… 54.192.174.35, 54.230.174.43, 54.230.174.121, …
Connecting to public-repo-1.hortonworks.com (public-repo-1.hortonworks.com)|54.192.174.35|:80… connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response… 404 Not Found
2015-04-13 12:59:11 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Please help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you disable your Firewall and check if you still get this problem?
Some corporate firewalls block Hortonworks (as a source of unauthorized software)